# How to adjust mouse position to camera coordinates in Pygame

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

I'm making a top-down game and so far I've added camera scrolling.

One of the mechanics in this game is the ability to throw balls towards your mouse.

However, since I've added camera scrolling, I've had problems with trying to calculate the mouse position relative to the camera scroll.

Here's how I calculate the scroll value:

```
    self.true_scroll[0] += (self.player.loc[0] - self.true_scroll[0] - self.screen_size[0] / 2 + self.player.width / 2) / 15
    self.true_scroll[1] += (self.player.loc[1] - self.true_scroll[1] - self.screen_size[1] / 2 + self.player.height / 2) / 15
    
    self.scroll = self.true_scroll.copy()
    self.scroll[0] = int(self.scroll[0])
    self.scroll[1] = int(self.scroll[1])
```

And here's my attempted code to get the mouse position based on the scroll and throw it towards that position:

```
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    
    mx -= scroll[0]
    my -= scroll[1]

    #For the scroll, I'm using the true_scroll value

    dx, dy = mx - self.loc[0], my - self.loc[1]
    angle = math.atan2(dy, dx)
    
    print(dx, dy)
            
    self.balls.append(Ball([self.loc[0], self.loc[1]], [math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)]))
```

The result is that the balls don't follow the mouse position and instead go to positions that are facing odd directions away from the mouse.

How do I make it so that I can make the mouse position relative to the scroll value?

Comment: The y-axis needs to be reversed (`-dy`) as the y-axis is generally pointing up, but in the PyGame coordinate system the y-axis is pointing down => `angle = math.atan2(-dy, dx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself! It was actually kind of easy.

All I had to do was not subtract the *mouse position*, but the *player's position* by the scroll value.

So the code became this:

```
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    sx, sy = self.loc[0] - scroll[0], self.loc[1] - scroll[1]
    
    dx, dy = mx - sx, my - sy
    angle = math.atan2(dy, dx)
                        
    self.balls.append(Ball([self.loc[0], self.loc[1]], [math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)]))
```

Hope this answer helps other  people